# how can i avoid the increasing of verion by adding relations?

Tags: grails

i have following domain class schema:

```
class A { static hasMany=[abRelations: AB] }
class B { static hasMany=[abRelations: AB] }
//relation table
class AB{
 A a
 B b
 String someAttribute
}
```

in some cases i definitely need the abRelations association, e.g. hql queries, criterias, ...

my problem is that when i create a new AB entry with

```
new AB(a: a, b: b, someAttribute: "hello").save()
```

the version field of A and B gets increased. can i avoid this by adding a special mapping option or something like this? i'm using the afterUpate event in some classes and this event is also fired when a add new relations -> thats my main problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the version field completely by adding the following to the domain class

```
static mapping = {
  version false
}
```

My understanding is that there's no way to exercise fine-grained control over when the `version` field gets incremented. You either have a `version` field and it automatically gets incremented every time a domain object is updated, or you don't have it at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i thought there would probably another solution. i don't want to loose the optimistic locking functionality by removing the version field from A and B. the best solution for my problem would be to call the code in the afterUpate closure manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have A and B version increased, keep you relations unidirectional, so A and B don't know about AB relations.

Comment: thanks, but i need the relations for performing hql queries and criterias. otherwise you would get hibernate path execption for those missing associations.